# How can I programmatically run mocha in debug mode?

Tags: node.js, debugging, testing, mocha.js

(Using mocha programmatically is described [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically), but I can't see how to start it in debug mode)

Comment: Do you mean running `mocha debug`?

Comment: Yes, but not in the terminal/cmd. The equivalent of that in a javascript file which I would then run with `node that_file.js`

Answer (score -2):

Set the environment to test with the following.

`process.env.NODE_ENV = "test";`

You will get a lot more output from your tests.

Comment: Already set, thanks for the tip :) Let me know if you find out a way to run debug programmatically, thanks